# how to update eclipse from 3.8.0 to 4.2 or 4.3 in ubuntu VM

Tags: eclipse, virtualbox

As the title, I used sudo apt-get update eclipse, but it turns out "E: The update command takes no arguments", which command should I use?

Answer (score 0):

`apt-get update` updates the sources for the updates. This should be run first.

Then run `apt-get install eclipse` to update eclipse from the sources gained in the first command

Comment: The newest version _built by Ubuntu and in their repositories_.

Comment: @nitind so how can update it? Do you mind to tell me in detail?

Comment: @user3352920 If you want to continue using packages provided by Ubuntu, you wait for them to build a newer version. Otherwise, you download your own copy from http://download.eclipse.org, unpack the tarball into a filespace you own, and run the eclipse executable yourself.